# 2*WorksheetFunction.Pi VS 2*3.14159265358979 (value of PI) difference in precision

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have noticed a precision difference between the following two calculations done in VBA (I'm using the VBA immediate window for output):

```
2 * WorksheetFunction.Pi = 6.28318530717959
2 *     3.14159265358979 = 6.28318530717958
```

Notice the last digit is 8, above was 9, even though 3.14159265358979 used in the calculation is the result given by "WorksheetFunction.Pi".

The first result is the more accurate result looking at the longer value of PI (2 * 3.141592653589793 = 6.283185307179**586** which would round to **59**).

Any explanation for the above, and is it possible to manually use a longer value of Pi in VBA?

Comment: Were you planning on asking a question? In most cases, you aren't going to need to worry about that many decimal places anyway. They are not significant.

Comment: It's making precision differences as the formulas are calculated many times, so getting a discrepancy between excel PI() and using the value of Pi in VBA

Comment: `? WorksheetFunction.Pi - 3.14159265358979`, `? WorksheetFunction.Pi - 3.141592653589793`

Comment: WorksheetFunction.Pi stops at at 79, it doesn't give the 3 at the end in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Pi) the PI function only returns 15 digits as a double.

There is an old but interesting conversation about PI-precision in VBA [here](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.excel.programming/c/LqH10-6QfbM) with multiple solutions by an Excel MVP, one would be declaring PI like this `PI = 4 * ATN(1)` and the other one where the MVP says "*For the most accuracy, declare PI like this...*" is this

```
Dim PI As Variant
PI = CDec("3.1415926535897932384626433833")
```

I have not verified if this actually works, but it seems pretty promising.

Comment: The link has some good points regarding how the PI constant is slightly different to PI() or WorksheetFunction.Pi